# Можно ли отключать роутеры в aiogram 3?

Tags: telegram-bot, telegram, aiogram

Делаю бота для игры в мафию. И нужно чтобы когда начиналась ночь хендлеры, которые работают днём не работали ночью

Comment: А просто внутри хендлеров написать `if ночь:` или `if not ночь:` не?

Comment: у меня так пол логики работает, просто думал можно сделать как то более оптимизировано